# change dropdown list selected item in update panel on page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting crazy with a simple task of changing a drop down selected item after page refresh which determine a grid view page value and if to enable or disable paging.

basically at the moment on page load if not post back I am binding the drop-down and set a default value and this works OK. However when I choose an item from the list and then I refresh the page, the default value (10) is not selected; by debugging, I can see that the code is fired also when I refresh the page though.

Below the code I am using; also note that all the markup is within an update panel and that although the value of 10 is not displaying properly, teh grid view does properly do paging by displaying 10 rows

```
     private void InitDdlPaging()
    {
        Paging.Add("All", "All");
        Paging.Add("5", "5");
        Paging.Add("10", "10");
        Paging.Add("20", "20");
        Paging.Add("30", "30");
        Paging.Add("50", "50");


        DdlPaging.Items.Clear();
        DdlPaging.DataSource = Paging;
        DdlPaging.DataTextField = "Value";
        DdlPaging.DataValueField = "Key";

        DdlPaging.DataBind();

        DdlPaging.Items[2].Selected = true;
        DdlPaging.SelectedIndex = 2;
        DdlPaging.SelectedValue = "10";
        DdlPaging.Text = "10";
    }
```

I call it on Page_Load as follows

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            InitValidators();
            InitPaging();
            InitDdlPaging();
        }
    }
```

Of course if I leave the page and come back then the default value of 10 is properly set

The issue is only happening in Firefox; not in Chorme or IE

Comment: Please check if your drop down is in the same update panel or not . for testing try putting it in a separate update panel and update mode as always and check.  And I feel you need to mark enableviewstate to true  for the dropdown

Comment: Hi Kishore, there is only one update panel on the page.

Comment: and marking enableviewstate to true does not solve the problem neither.. this is weird....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the issue is happening only in Firefox 32 not in the latest Chrome or IE from 8 to 11 therefore I'll leave it as it is while I am trying to investigate a possible solution for Firefox.